# visual studio 2017: What is keyboard shortcut for Window --> New Window

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working with a file in the text editor.
I want to open a 2nd copy.
Presently, I click Window menu  >  New Window

Is there keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Alt+W+N
```

All visual studio shortcut [here](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks ...  Duh!  Of course!  I forgot about the Alt access to any menu command.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any keyboard shortcut to the **Window.NewWindow** command in Visual Studio keyboard options:

[image]